# How to implement a cache attribute?

Tags: c#, caching, attributes, properties

How can I implement a `CacheAttribute` so I can have the same logic for all properties in one place?

I am doing this to cache

```
[TestClass]
public class All
{
    public string N
    {
        get
        {
            var value =
                MemoryCache.Default.Get("Website.Tests.All.N") as string;

            if (value != null)
            {
                return value;
            }

            value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff");

            MemoryCache.Default.Add("Website.Tests.All.N", value,
                new CacheItemPolicy
                {
                    AbsoluteExpiration =
                        new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
                });

            return value;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Extension()
    {
        var start = N;

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var end = N;

        Assert.AreEqual(start, end);
    }
}
```

And I want to use this instead

```
[TestClass]
public class All
{
    [Cache(Duration=5000)]
    public string N
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff");
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Extension()
    {
        var start = N;

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var end = N;

        Assert.AreEqual(start, end);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this syntax sugar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching attribute for method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328819/caching-attribute-for-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to "take over" the `get` method for the property so as to inspect a cache first before returning the "actual" value from your property.  Since there is no way to perform property interception on an ad-hoc basis, you'll have to plan ahead for this facility.

One approach would be to use interfaces and write your classes to the interface.  For example,

```
public interface IAll 
{
    string N { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use [proxies](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) to create a wrapper around the original instance of `All` that also implements this interface.   Furthermore, since you're fully in charge of the property now, you can check the cache whenever the `getter` is called.  Since you'll have the `PropertyInfo`/`MethodInfo` at your disposal, you should have no trouble generating a unique key per property.

So, whenever you would instantiate an instance of `All`, you also instantiate this proxy, passing it the instance of `All`.  All subsequent usages of that instance of `All` should instead be passed the proxy.  Like any class factory implementation, this requires you to forgo use of the **new** operator.

Alternatively, you can use **virtual** methods instead of interfaces.